# Testing If Mal-Dosing Exceeds a Certain Threshold

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, central-limit-theorem

Suppose you have mal-dosing data of some medication (in percent). You want to know if mal-dosing on average exceeds 5% regardless of over- or underdosing.

**Can I do a simple t-test?** (if I assume iid data)

The random variable (absolute mal-dosing) lives only on the positive real line. My guess is that the CLT does not require a RV to have support over the entire real line and therefore a simple t-test is valid. Am I right?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything to answer here: $Y=|X_i|$ is a random variable, too: so apply what you know to $Y.$  This leads one to suspect there is some special characteristic of a problem you are facing that leads you to pose this question, but what exactly is that problem?

Comment: The situation is as follows: I have mal-dosing data of some medication (in percent). Some patients are overdosed (positive data points) some are underdosed (negative data points) only in theory patients can be exactly correctly dosed. I would like to test the $H_0$ that average mal-dosing does not exceed 5% in absolute terms. Can I just do a simple t-test? Is it not a problem, that the support of the RV is just the positive real line?

Comment: Please add this information to your post itself.  In general, a t-test *might* be applicable but it depends on how much data you have and the assumptions you make about the statistical distribution of those data.  There are alternative tests, too.  Finally, one might wonder about how meaningful or useful the hypothesis about an *average* mal-dosing in a population might be because it appears to have no meaningful interpretation in terms of toxicological endpoints.  Exploring this question might lead you to formulating more effective analyses of your data.